# What Block Isn't Covered?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, code-coverage

Visual Studio 2013 is showing my code coverage for this (simplified for this example) object as missing a block:

[image: code coverage]

As far as I know, that `if` should have exactly two states.  Pass and fail.  And debugging my tests shows that each of those conditions is executed once.  Specifically with these two tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanNotHaveNegativeServiceWindow()
{
    // arrange
    var request = new CreateCaseRequest
    {
        ServiceWindowStart = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 12, 00, 00),
        ServiceWindowEnd = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 11, 00, 00)
    };

    // act
    var result = request.GetValidationErrors();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count());
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanHaveServiceWindow()
{
    // arrange
    var request = new CreateCaseRequest
    {
        ServiceWindowStart = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 11, 00, 00),
        ServiceWindowEnd = new DateTime(2014, 12, 31, 12, 00, 00)
    };

    // act
    var result = request.GetValidationErrors();

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(0, result.Count());
}
```

One test validates the positive result of that specific `if` condition, the other validates the negative result.  What block isn't covered?  What logical condition exists that I'm missing?

Comment: what if they are null or both equal?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Other tests cover those cases.  That `if` is only ever reached if both of them have a value anyway.  If they're both equal then that's a false condition of the `if`, isn't it?  As in, no different than any other false condition?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do (I removed my old comment) Could you try `if (ServiceWindowStart.Value > ServiceWindowEnd.Value)` instead?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Very interesting, that seems to have done the trick.  I guess there's some extra blocks created in the comparison of a `Nullable<T>` by the compiler.  Logically I've covered those cases, but the compiler doesn't know that for that particular comparison.  Go ahead and add as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compare `Nullable<T>` values, C# compiler creates additional checks to see that the  `Nullable<T>`s have values. These checks will always come out the same way in your code, because you have already done all the `null` checking explicitly.

Changing the condition to

```
if (ServiceWindowStart.Value > ServiceWindowEnd.Value)
```

should fix this problem.

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaaaa!  Lost 3 hours on this.  My code was in a custom comparer.    /* x and y are same type */      if (x.MyNullableDate.HasValue && y.MyNullableDate.HasValue && x.MyNullableDate == y.MyNullableDate)   I KNOW I had every permutation covered via UnitTests.  Adding .Value to both...fixed the coverage.  Thanks.   if (x.MyNullableDate.HasValue && y.MyNullableDate.HasValue && x.MyNullableDate.Value == y.MyNullableDate.Value)

Answer (score 2):

Light beige doesn't mean the code has not been covered. It means it's been only partially covered. Your `ServiceWindowStart` and `ServiceWindowEnd` are nullable. But you test them only with values. And you doesn't test for equality. Adding test for null values and for the case when they are equal should cover missing test cases.

Another possible reason of this result can be related to the fact that code coverage is performed on IL code and not on C# code. And the IL equivalent may not be fully covered or the structure of the code may not be preserved.

Optimizing your build may solve the problem. Go to Solution Explorer -> Properties -> Build tab -> Check the "Optimize code" check box.

Run the code analysis with this option selected.

Here's interesting blog post that covers this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ddietric/archive/2009/10/21/all-the-wonderful-colors-of-code-coverage.aspx

Comment: Other tests (not shown here) cover `null` values.  Besides, if either value is `null` then `if (ServiceWindowStart.HasValue && ServiceWindowEnd.HasValue)` prevents the flow from ever entering that block.  The `if` condition in question is only for cases where neither value is `null`.  I get that it's partially covered, what I'm not seeing is what part isn't covered.

Comment: Did you test the equality case as well. Plus option when one value is null and the other not null?

Comment: I just added a test for equal values, same result. Which doesn't surprise me because two equal values would have the same result of a `>` comparison as two unequal but less than values. And yes, I do test for `null` values in other tests. But those aren't relevant, because the `if` condition immediately before the one in question will never be satisfied if either value is `null`. That's an entirely different branch of logic.

Comment: Try optimizing your code. I added instructions in my answer.